# SwiftUI MultiDatePicker with Custom Binding

Tags: swiftui, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to use the MultiDatePicker in SwiftUI, but can't get it working properly with a custom binding. The problem I'm facing is that it's acting as a single date picker, not a mutli date picker (selecting a 2nd date, deselects the 1st selected date).

This is part of a KMM project, and I have a viewModel that's written in Kotlin and lives in shared code. There is a Swift wrapper around this that holds/exposes a single state object containing all state (as an observableObject), and passes events back to the shared code.

Throughout the project we manually create bindings like this:

```
Binding(
    get: {state.property},
    set: {onEvent(someEvent(value: $0)}
)
```

This usually works fine, but I'm having problems with the MultiDatePicker.

Here's my datepicker code:

```
 MultiDatePicker(
     SharedRes.strings().please_select_dates.asString(),
     selection: Binding(
         get: {
              print(newBenefit.blackoutDates)
              return Set( newBenefit.blackoutDates.compactMap{
                 cal.dateComponents([.calendar, .era, .year, .month, .day], from: $0.toSwiftDate()!)}
               )
         },
         set: { value in
              blackoutDatesChanged(value.compactMap{cal.date(from: $0)})
         }
      )
)
Text(newBenefit.blackoutDates.compactMap{$0.toSwiftDate()}.toMultiDateString())
```

`newBenefit.blackoutDates` is a list of KotlinXLocalDates and `blackoutDatesChanged` is defined as `let blackoutDatesChanged: ([Date]) -> Void`

I've added a `print(newBenefit.blackoutDates)` inside the get, to try and see what's happening.

When I select the first date, the `get` block is run twice - I get an empty list printed, followed by a list containing the selected date. The text below the picker correctly shows the date I've selected. I.e. `newBenefit.blackoutDates` is correctly being updated by my `set`.

When I select the second date, I get the same result. I get an empty list printed, followed by a list containing a single date (the 2nd selected date).

It seems like - on selecting a date, the datepicker is calling the `get` to get a list of previous dates, then adding the newly selected date into that, then calling the `set` with that new list (which will update my state, triggering a new call to `get`). Setting breakpoints appears to confirm this - `get` gets hit, then `set`, then `get` again!

However, every time on that first 'get' call (when clicking a date), my list of current dates is showing as empty. Almost as though the `get` isn't reading the current list, but reading the state as it was when the datepicker was first initialized. So, the previously selected date is ignored, and when calling the `set` it's only passing in that 2nd selected date.

Any help figuring this out is greatly appreciated.

Comment: newBenefit.blackoutDates Likely doesn’t play by SwiftUI’s rules. Usually this is a projectedValue/wrappedValue issue